# src folder not created when creating simple Intellij java gradle Project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am following the instructions to create a simple IntelliJ Project with Gradle support and the src folder is not created (I guess this is the base of any Java Project)
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html

1. New Project: I check Gradle and Java - next
2. Added Artefact ID -> next
3. "Use auto-import", "using explicit module groups", "create separate Module per source set", "Use default Gradle wrapper" -> next
4. Give a project name -> next

I have no src folder. I am not able to add a new class.

[image]

When doing the same without gradle I have the src folder.

**UPDATE**
Adding a module called "src" works, but then I have a module called src and a folder in it called src. But this is a hack. Just bought IntelliJ for 200 bucks and I hope this can be solved in a more professional way :-)

Comment: Why do you add a "module"? Just add the directory.

Comment: What do you see when clicking on the little arrow next to Project

Comment: @baao: I see what you can see in the screenshot. Project is already opened in the Screenshot.

Comment: @JB Nizet. No Creating directory is not the solution. Already tried. After creating directory the context is still not java, because I can't create a class in that folder.

Comment: That's normal. Java classes go into src/main/java. Not in src.

Comment: src/main/java is also not there. That is not the point. It is not normal to manually add this folders. That is the point. See my answer. In my oppinion this should be a task for the IDE and not for the developer. I even was not able to add folders manually. I had to configure this hidden magical checkbox in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, there is a bug in 2018.1 version when the project structure for a new Gradle project is not created automatically:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189674 I hope it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**For Windows** the solution is. To go manually into:
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> check the "Create directories for empty content roots automatically".

**For Mac** the solution is. To go manually into:
Intellij IDEA -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> check the "Create directories for empty content roots automatically".

Comment: On Mac, go to IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle.  Couldn't agree more - it's stupid.  If this is a bug as @Andrey suggests, hopefully it will be sorted soon.

Comment: In IntelliJ 2018.1.5 it is in _Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle_. Also the setting is a _Project-level setting_, that means it must be set per prorject and is not available from the start-screen when no project is opened.

Comment: What about Linux? Edit: It's the same as on Windows.

Comment: Seems like this was removed in the recent 2019.2 update :(

Comment: @npstr I also don't see this option. When I'm creating a new Gradle->Java project only build.gradle & settings.gradle file gets created in new empty project... How did you fix it...

Answer (score 34):

Just right-click on your project directory and choose `New -> Directory`.
 Select all four to be created.

1. src/main/java
2. src/main/resource
3. src/test/java
4. src/test/resource

[image: right click on project directory]

[image: choose the four choices]

found the answer here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206806425-Source-Directories-Not-Being-Created-In-New-Project

Answer (score 12):

@here
A quick fix that worked for me. Once you have created the gradle project as mentioned in the question

- open the gradle sidebar on the right hand side.
- click settings
- a new dialog box will appear.
- In this dialog box check the option "create directories for empty contents roots automatically"
- then click apply and src folders will be created for you ..

Images are attached for clarity.

[Open the gradle sidebar on the right hand side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pLtb.png)

[Check the option "create directories for empty contents roots automatically"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPUuN.png)

Comment: what to do If I don't have a check option "create directories for empty contents roots automatically". Before it created the src folder without any problems;)

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer. Only the method of opening the settings differs, but it's same dialog

Answer (score 5):

### As of January 2022 with Intellij IDEA 2021.1.3 and Gradle 6.8

**First of all, right-click your project main folder ...**

[image: First Step]

**Go to > New > Directory...**

[image: Second Step]

**After clicking the "Directory" option, this will open a dialog containing available options of "Gradle Source Sets" to add.**

[image: Third Step]

**You can select what *"Gradle Source Sets"* you want to add. In my case, I have already added the *"src/main/kotlin"* (Notice it's not displayed in the options).**

Comment: What's the difference with this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60687501/4854931

Answer (score 3):

If enabling the "Create directories for empty content roots automatically" setting does not show the src directory, check the project structure and try creating and deleting a dummy module.

1. File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Project Name -> Confirm that src is part of the hierarchy and exit out of the pop up
2. Right click on the root folder of the project -> New -> Module
3. The IDE may have refreshed, along with the visibility of the src folder

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me. Finally, had to go raw.

```
gradle init --type java-library
```

Followed [Mkyong's page on gradle init](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-java-project-structure-automatically/)

Then, simply 'Open' project in Intellij. Then updated project settings related to JAVA_HOME and Gradle home (Chances are these were related to my specific installation).

Comment: This does not work unfortunately:
> Task :init SKIPPED
The build file 'build.gradle' already exists. Skipping build initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Add a directory named 'src'. Right click on it and then click Mark Directory as Sources Root.